# How to make a git repository read-only?

Tags: git, readonly

I have some git repositories accessed remotely through SSH and I want to make some of them read-only to prevent more pushes. Some people have remotes pointing to these repositories.

These bare repositories were initialised `--shared=group`, so is setting file permissions to 660 for all files good enough to still allow SSH access, but disallow writes? Or is there an easier way?

Cheers.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is more than one possible way to do this.

- If your users each have a shell account (perhaps limited), and each of them accessing git repositories via their own account, you can use **filesystem permissions** to control SSH access to git repositories.  On Unix those would be write permissions on *directories*, perhaps with the help of creating a group and specific permissions for a group (with "sticky group ID" set).
- Pushing requires **`git-receive-pack`** to be in $PATH of user, and be executable for them... although I am not sure how feasible this approach would be.
- You can use **`update` or `pre-receive` hook** to do access control to repository, for example using [update-paranoid](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=contrib/hooks/update-paranoid;hb=HEAD) example hook from `contrib/hooks` in git sources.
- With larger number of users you could be better with using a **tool to manage access to git repositories**, like [Gitosis](http://swik.net/gitosis) (in Python, requires setuptools) or [Gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) (in Perl).
- For read only access you can setup **[git daemon](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html)** to provide read-only anonymous (and unauthenticated) access via `git://` protocol, instead of access via SSH protocol.

  See documentation for `url.<base>.insteadOf` config variable for a way to ease the transition from SSH to GIT protocol.

---

See also Chapter 4. "[Git on the Server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)" of [Pro Git](http://progit.org) book by Scott Chacon (CC-BY-NC-SA licensed).

Comment: Should note that for filesystem permissions, you can use chmod, as suggested by Pat Notz.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas (everyone). Inspired by the update-paranoid example hook, I now have a hook in my repos which simply does `echo "Closed for all pushes" ; exit 1`

Comment: @SteveFolly If your comment was an answer, I would vote for it instead of the accepted answer. Yours is short, to the point, and works.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn I added a proper answer based on Steves comment.

Comment: Is this possible to do with GitHub Enterprise without access to configuring the entire instance meaning an org/repo owner could do it? It seems like the admins of the actual server would need to help you out per this document: https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/admin/developer-workflow/creating-a-pre-receive-hook-script

Answer (score 17):

A `pre-receive` hook that simply prints an informative message and exits with a non zero status does the job.

Assuming you put some meaningful information in your message, it also cuts down on the queries from frustrated users asking why they can't push:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "=================================================="
echo "This repository is no longer available for pushes."
echo "Please visit blah blah yadda yadda ...."
echo "=================================================="
exit 1
```

Remember to set the executable permission for the script and to make sure is owned by the right user and/or group, or else it will not execute and will not give any warning.

Answer (score 8):

```
chmod -R a-w /path/to/repo.git
```

Comment: "make some of them read-only to prevent more pushes" – this would prevent pulling, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662205/how-to-make-a-git-repository-read-only#comment1604472_1663441):

1. Update your `hooks/pre-receive` file with the following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   echo "Closed for all pushes" ; exit 1
   ```

This way, all users trying to push changes to this repo will receive the message above and the push will be rejected.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. By the way, it's worth mentioning that the hooks directory lives under the repository root filesystem path.

Answer (score 3):

Since git relies primarily on the filesystem for access control, that will work.  Note that in your permissions, the world has no access to the file, but the user and group have read/write access.  If you want world-readable, your permissions should be `0444`.

You could do further fine-grained control by setting the repo permissions as `0664` where the user is `nobody` and the group is something like `gitdevs`.  Then, only people in the `gitdevs` group will have the ability to write to the repo, but the world can read from it.

**Follow-up** [Here is a link](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/) that covers various ways to share your repo and covers come pro's & cons and access control features.

Comment: 666 is world readable and writable files.  776 is world and group readable, writable and executable and other users read and write.  Not sure where you got the numbers you're recommending, but they're generally dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, corrected my answer.  Too much typing, not enough thinking.

Answer (score 1):

If you need access control as well, check out [gitosis](http://swik.net/gitosis). Pretty easy to set-up and you can use a simple script to control who can do what.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is the git protocol, but it requires the git daemon to be running.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I used limiting access to path "/repo.git/git-receive-pack" to achive result that the repository is read-write for some users and read-only for some others. In httpd config it looks like this:

```
    <Location /repo.git/>
            Require group developers developers-ro
    </Location>

    <Location /repo.git/git-receive-pack>
            Require group developers
    </Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am just a user of our GitLab (and I didn't wanted to bother the admins in the first step), I searched for another way and found one:

- Open the GitLab webinterface and go to the repository you want to set to read-only
- Choose **Settings > Repository**
- Expand **Protected Branches**
- Add the master branch and set **Allowed to merge** and **Allowed to push** to **No one**
- If the master branch is protected already, you can set these values in the list below

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if you're trying to make a *Github* repo read-only, you can archive it: https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/archiving-a-github-repository/about-archiving-repositories