# Give Read-only access to a git repository

Tags: git, permissions, ssh

I'm not sure if this should go here, or on superuser (as it seems to pertain to both topics), so I've put it here, if it's not appropriate, I'll go ask it on superuser.

Anyway, I have a git repository that can't go completely open source (otherwise I would just put it on github and be done with it), and I have a server that I have ssh access (but not superuser access) to, this server has all of the git binaries already on it.  I need to give someone read-only access to this git-repo (or at least read-only access to some of the branches, although I would imagine that's a lot harder).

Currently I'm using ssh to push and poll my local git repo to this server.  Is there any way to give another person read only access to the server?  (I suppose I am fine with us both having write access to the repo, although I'm not sure how to do that with unix permissions, as I don't have the ability to make new unix groups as I don't have superuser permissions).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662205/how-to-make-a-git-repository-read-only -- looks like the best option is to use the git daemon, but ymmv.

Comment: Maybe overkill for your case, but have you looked at [gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)?

Comment: Ya...I did, it seemed like there was so many different ways I could have screwed up my account on the sever (because I would have to use the non-root access method), so I would rather not do it.

Comment: Why does this question have the "cvs" tag?

Comment: Because I had always thought cvs of a generic scm, and never realized it was a specific scm package.  I removed it.

Comment: The generic variant of CVS is VCS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the git protocol.
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html

It'll be public to everybody, which may not be what you want, but nobody will be able to do a push over git://.

You can control what branches they can access by only pushing the branches you want to be accessible to it.
I would do this by having a separate clone from your ssh enabled private repository, and then add that as a remote.  Then you can do `git push pub public-branch`, so then `private-branch` won't be accessible from that location.

Comment: Ya, I'm thinking this is the best (or at least the easiest) way to do it.  I just obfuscated the path of directory with like this: projectname-small-set-of-random-symbols, which I think will be okay, as I'm not a big target, and the parent directory isn't world readable.  Although I have one issue.  Although I need a bit of help.  I had already made the branch, and pushed it to the server (the bare version) (I renamed it as mentioned above).  Than I put the git-daemon-export-ok file in it, and ran the git daemon.  The problem is that I have to keep git daemon running in order to keep the...

Comment: ...branch publicly available, and it stops whenever I close the connections, etc.  So is there any way (without superuser access) that I can set it up to have that working all the time?  Thanks

Comment: Try running `nohup git daemon &`.  This will make it execute in the background and it won't exit when you disconnect your ssh session (no hangup).

Comment: Hmm...that worked, thanks.  Hopefully it won't have any bad side effects.

Answer (score 1):

In .ssh/authorized_keys you can specify a command that is always run when a given public key is used to log in. You could probably set this to `git-upload-pack /path/to/repo.git` and git pull just might work. There may very well be non-obvious security pitfalls with this approach.

See [the sshd manual page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8) for the format of the authorized_keys file.

Comment: Hmm...it looks like my .ssh folder doesn't actually have an authorized_keys file, only a known_hosts one.

Comment: You can create one, with multiple public keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up ACLs to manage the rights on your repositories... There is a lot of details about this topic in the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). And according to what I have read so far, yes you can apply this on select branches if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of **tools for managing git repositories** like [gitosis](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git) (in Python) or [gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) (in Perl), which allow for controlling acces to repositories (or you can use your own solution, similar to example [update-paranoid](http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/blob/HEAD:/contrib/hooks/update-paranoid) update hook).

The other solution would be to use one of [git hosting sites](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitHosting) that offer private repositories (e.g. [Codaset](http://codaset.com/pricing) provides 1 (semi)private repository in free plan, with 200 MB disk space limit).

Answer (score 0):

You can have private repositories on Github...they just cost a few dollars a month depending on the # of developers. You can control access VERY easily from there.

Comment: VERY easily ... great solution :)