# In a git repository, how can I create only read-access users?

Tags: git, composer-php, repository, credentials, user-permissions

I have a problem with my module in the git repository. I have a .htpasswd file where I added some users passwords using command     "`htpasswd .htpasswd userName`"    . When I add my repository to a composer.json (    `composer config repositories vcs https://myrepository.git`    ) and install a module using     "`composer require vendor/module-name`"    command, the module install correctly inserting a user and password of the .htpasswd file. The problem is that this users can make git push to my repository and change the code. I want to create users who only can install the module and not make any push.

For example:

I have a module for sale. A customer buy my module, so I have to create a credentials, user and password, to give to customer for he can install using composer this module with the credentials. This credentials are only to install module, not to make push.

I want to create credentials for this user only for install module. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a git repository read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662205/how-to-make-a-git-repository-read-only)

Comment: [Give Read-only access to a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908528/give-read-only-access-to-a-git-repository)