# Git disable pushing from local repository

Tags: git, configuration, clone

I have a repository with some core code in it, and for each client I wish to clone it so I can do git pull everytime a client wants to upgrade to the newest functionality.

In the interest of not screwing things up and making changes that only one company sees, is there a way to only allow fetches on a local repository basis?  I still want to be able to push changes to the core repo from my dev environment, but don't want production machines to be able to push.

Comment: I believe it depends on what you're using for hosting your git repository. Is it Github, your own git server or smth else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a git repository read-only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662205/how-to-make-a-git-repository-read-only)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Specify a **non-existing pushurl** in the remote section of the clone-source repository (called origin) in the file `.git/config`. Example:

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = <url>
        pushurl = www.non-existing-url.com
```

Or if you don't like editing the config file of the repository you can type:

```
$ git config remote.origin.pushurl www.non-existing.com
```

When pushing you'll get an error message like:

```
$ git push
fatal: 'www.non-existing-url.com' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Of course you'll need to edit the config file of each cloned repository.

Comment: This looks like the info I was seeking.  I just disassembled my repos as I'm reassembling them in a new way, but once I get them back together I'll test it out.

Answer (score 7):

I find the remote command more useful so I don't have to mess with configs directly.

```
git remote set-url --push origin www.non-existing-url.com
```

should work as well