# Setting read-only access for specific branches on GitHub repo

Tags: github

I created two branch on a GitHub repository but would like to set read-only permission for some members on one branch (master branch) and allow write persmission to another branch (dev branch). Is this possible on GitHub?

My temporary solution is create one public repository and one private repository like an answer [on git branch permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248246/git-branch-permissions/13248418#13248418).

Comment: You're looking for real secure solution or preventing accidents will be enough?

Comment: @Agis My problem is on Github, not my own Git server. Thank for your attention :-)

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk I would like to preventing accidents :-)

Comment: @RongNK Refer to https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-different-access-permissions

Comment: Thank @Agis, you can see: Github provide repository level restriction(not branch level restriction) :|

Answer (score 2):

bitbucket do this for you
when you want to invite someone to your repository in bitbucket you can set his/her access type to master (read/write) ,you can simply select read and that user wont write to the master 
bitbucket is a server for your repository that manage your project with git
(sorry for poor english)

Comment: Thank you! Now, my work is on `Github`, i can not move to `Bitbucket` :-)