# Is it possible to make read-only comments in a R Script?

Tags: r

I am working on a project which requires me to give the user a list of do/dont's which shouldn't be edited.
So is it possible to make read-only comments.
Any help would be appreciated thanks!!!
(Note: its not a rshiny script)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. R scripts are regular files, all parts of them are editable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a read only repository and put your code there?

[How to make a git repository read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662205/how-to-make-a-git-repository-read-only)

I never had to use sections of the code with read only access, and I am not sure if we can make this kind of thing.